# ¿Como llamar una función dentro de la misma "clase" en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de emular una clase en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), deseo llamar una función que ya establecí en el mismo documento por medio de un evento `onclick`, tengo lo siguiente:

```
function clase(){


// Consultar
this.consultar = function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { consulta: query },
        beforeSend:function(){

        },
        success:function(response){
            // omito lo anterior por que hasta acá esta todo bien
            // el problema lo tengo al momento de hacer llamar la función
            var datos = JSON.parse(response);

            // datatable
            var idTabla = $('#tabla').DataTable({ 
                lengthMenu:[[5,10],[5,10]]
            });
            // limpio el datatable
            idTabla.row().clear();
            for (var i = 0; i < datos.length ; i++) {
            // inserto los datos en el datatable
                idTabla.row.add([  
                    datos[i].documento,
                    datos[i].nombre+" "+datos[i].apellidos,
                    datos[i].correo,
                    datos[i].telefono,
                    datos[i].email,
                    // creo una etiqueta <a></a> y en este llamo un evento "onclick" en el cual deseo llamar la otra funcion
                    '<a href="#" class="on-primary edit-row" onclick=\' this.estado("'+datos[i].id+'", "'+datos[i].estado+'"); \'><i id="'+datos[i].id+'"class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'
                ]);
            }
            idTabla.draw(true);
        }
    });
}

this.estado = function(id, estado){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "url",
        dataType:"html", 
        async: true,
        data: { 
            id:id, 
            ingresoNuevo: 3, 
            estado: estado 
        },
        beforeSend:function(){
            $("#"+id).removeClass().addClass( "fa fa-refresh fa-spin" );
        },
        success:function(response){
            // llamo la función de consulta para volver a mostrar la tabla esta ves con el estado actualizado
            this.consultar();
        }
    });
}


}
```

Cabe notar que faltan algunos datos, pero los omiti por que creo que son irrelevantes para la pregunta ya que lo que busco es saber como puedo llamar la función `estado` en el evento `onclick.

Comment: Se recomienda (convención) usar mayúsculas para las funciones que corresponden a clases. https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml#Naming

Comment: Gracias por el aporte lo voy a tener en cuenta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método inline sería:

```
<a href="#" onclick="(new clase()).estado();">bla</a>
```

Usando la administración de eventos de jQuery y asumiendo que ya está definido todo:

```
$(".selectorCSS").click(function(){
  (new clase()).estado();
});
```

Comment: brutal!! muchas gracias !!!

Answer (score 0):

Otro método que puedes utilizar es almacenarlo en una variable:

```
var MiClase = {
     metodoPublico = function(str){
           return str;
     }
}
```

Y al necesitarlo:

```
$('.miclase').on('click', function(){ MiClase.metodoPublico('Hola locochon')});
```

Incluso así podrías hacer un "tipo" Singlenton, pero bueno todo depende de que es lo que quiras hacer.